# How to add directives to php.ini on AWS Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, elastic-beanstalk

I'd like to add these PHP settings to my Elastic Beanstalk environment:

```
upload_max_filesize = 64M
post_max_size = 64M
```

These options cannot be set with [option_settings](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#customize-containers-format-options) in `.ebextensions`:

```
Namespace                                    | Extend
---------------------------------------------|-------
aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment | Yes
aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:php:phpini    | No
```

How can I add custom settings to `php.ini` in an Elastic Beanstalk container?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The cleanest way I found is to use a [.ebextensions config file](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#customize-containers-format-files) in my project archive:

Sample `.ebextensions/project.config` file:

```
files:
  "/etc/php.d/project.ini" :
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      upload_max_filesize = 64M
      post_max_size = 64M
```

When the application version is deployed, this will write a custom config file in the `php.d` directory, that will override any `php.ini` setting.

Comment: So does that mean `/etc/php.d/project.ini` file is automatically created when the new app version is deployed?

Comment: @user1448031 Yes it's automatically created!

Comment: Is it also applicable in Ubuntu. I'm having the same issue.

Comment: I tried this and it caused my Laravel app to crash.  Any thoughts as to what might have gone wrong?

Comment: Never mind, it did work, thanks!  My issue was unrelated - for some reason eb deploy isn't working but uploading a zip is, which is a whole other ball of wax.  Once I manually deployed it it worked like a charm!